# What's does `~uintptr_t(value)` method body mean? C++

Tags: c++

```
typedef uintptr_t disguised_ptr_t;
inline disguised_ptr_t DISGUISE(id value) { return ~uintptr_t(value); }
```

I read objc runtime source code recently, above code confused me.

Comment: Convert the value to an unsigned integer big enough to hold a pointer, and then take its 1-complement.

Comment: `~` is the [bitwise NOT operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators)

Answer (score 4):

First it does a conversion (a.k.a. a *cast*) of `value` to the type `uintptr_t`. Then it does a bitwise negation (complement) of the resulting value.

The code in the function is basically equivalent to

```
uintptr_t temporary = value;
return ~temporary;
```